# Rendering html tags in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>
  Hello {{superscript('hello')}}
  </h1>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
    superscript(input) {
        return '<sup>' + input + '</sup>'
    }
  }
})
```

I want this to render:

> Hello <sup>hello</sup>

But instead it renders the tags themselves without turning it into a superscript. JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agreyfield91/eywraw8t/188244/

Is there a way to add html tags through a Vue.js method?

Comment: you need change your span to this:  <span v-html="superscript('hello')"></span>

Comment: v-html ...we use..... v-html for inner html ...

Comment: please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/bzsjwx5c/2/

Comment: and read the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of rendering the html, you need to bind it:

```
{{ result }}  => <span v-html="result"></span>
```

In your case:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>
  Hello <span v-html="superscript('hello')"></span>
  </h1>
  <h1>
  What I want it to look like:   Hello <sup>hello</sup>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to all be in the method though. Is it possible to do this without editing the html?