# Render html from string vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm struggling with a problem, I want to create a chat app, and the users to be able to tag each other, by using @. For example, user1 type in chat input 'hi @user2', the output should look the same, but '@user2' be a link instead of simple text, I figured how to do that, but the problem is that, if user input for example html tags, it's rendered as html.

HTML:

```
<span v-html="chatFormat(chat.text)"></span>
```

VUE:

```
chatFormat(text) {
  var words = text.split(" ");
  var newStr = '';
  words.forEach(function (word) {
  if (word.includes('@') >= 1) {
    if (word.charAt(0) == '@') {
      word = '{{ <a href="/user" class="font-weight-bold" style="text-decoration:none">' + word + '</a> }}';
    }
  }
  newStr = newStr + ' ' + word;
  });
  return newStr;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226843/381282

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering html tags in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430422/rendering-html-tags-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using `v-html` directive renders value as HTML - it's not parsed for variables.
You could change Your code and get rid of `{{}}` so only link would appear in the output.

```
word = '<a href="/user" class="font-weight-bold" style="text-decoration:none">' + word + '</a>';
```

But, be aware that using v-html to display user-input is a risky thing. User input should be escaped first to get rid of potential harmful code.
(You can check [Sanitizing user input before adding it to the DOM in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794137/sanitizing-user-input-before-adding-it-to-the-dom-in-javascript) as *Michal Levý* suggested)

I would also suggest using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
chatFormat(text) {
  // using let instead of var for declaring variables in the local scope
  let safeText= this.sanitizeHTML(text), // for security reasons
      words = safeText.split(" "),
      newStr = '';

  words.forEach(word => { // arrow function
    if (word.includes('@') >= 1) {
      if (word.charAt(0) == '@') {
        word = `<a href="/user" class="font-weight-bold" style="text-decoration:none">${word}</a>`; // template literal
      }
    }
    newStr = newStr + ' ' + word;
  });

  return newStr;
},

// This should be a secure sanitization method from some library
sanitizeHTML(string) {
  return string
},
```

Answer (score 0):

A subject that has been discussed an number of times.

in Vuejs.org: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

in stackoverflow.com: (one of many) [Rendering html tags in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430422/rendering-html-tags-in-vue-js)